# sequelize for NodeJS: are these features supported?

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

Here are some questions about features supported by sequelize ([sequelize project site](http://sequelizejs.com)) that I would like to clear up before deciding whether or not to use it:

1. Chaining (efficiency): when chaining multiple queries, are these collected into one request to the database (as a batch of operations), or is each one sent separately?
2. Chaining (success/error): when chaining multiple queries, when is the success event emitted and what happens on error? Is "success" emitted only if *all* operations succeeded? And if there was an error, does it rollback all operations (i.e. are the chained operations treated as a transaction)
3. Filtering associations: Say a `Crowd` object has the relation `Crowd.hasMany(Person)`. You can get all the associated people by executing `crowd.getPersons()`, but is it possible to select a subset of them, like `crowd.getPersons({where: { age: 30 }})`?
4. Getting associated objects that are related by two or more steps: Say a `Crowd` object as the relation `Crowd.hasMany(Person)` and `Person` has the relation `Person.hasMany(Pet)`. Is it possible to get all the pets of people in a crowd by executing something like `crowd.getPersons().getPets()`, and if so does this get sent as multiple request to the database, or just one request?
5. "Deep" object: I want to define a person as the object:

   ```
   sequelize.define('Person', {
       name: {
           first: <a string>,
           last: <a string>
       }
   });
   ```

   Is this allowed? (Note that name is not going to be a column of the database table, but first and last will be)
6. "Calculated" object: Is it possible to add a field to the object that is calculated from other fields of the object? For example:

   ```
   sequelize.define('Person', {
       name: {
           first: <a string>,
           last: <a string>,
           full: <name.first + ' ' + name.last> // <-- this field
       }
   });
   ```

   So that the `name.full` field isn't actually stored in the database (which is a waste of space) but rather just calculated from the other two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.: You can use for super duper batch processing the QueryChainer. Nevertheless, every command will be executed separated.

2.: Using the QueryChainer, the success event will only be triggered if everything was fine. Error is triggered if there occured one or multiple errors. The first param of the bound method will be an array of errors.

3.: Hmm I'm not 100% sure, but imho it's not yet supported.

4.: Nope not possible but more complicated and less fancy with:

```
crowd.getPeople().success(function(people) {
  people.forEach(function(person){
    person.getPets().success... // you have to collect them on your own
  })
})
```

5.: Nope. But I also don't understand why you would do that.

6.: Yep, check this http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/models#expansion-of-models and:

```
Person = sequelize.define('Person', {foo:Sequelize.STRING}, {
  instanceMethods: {
    fullname: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: So for #2, if there is an error with one of the requests, will it rollback all requests (as would happen in a transaction)? Or are the chained requests not treated as a transaction?

Comment: they aren't treated as a transaction but executed happily separated from each other and returning all occured errors as the result

Comment: It would be nice if instead of simply having the ability to add instance methods, if you could define getters and setters that were used when serializing the object.

Comment: About the point 3, I'm not sure if the newer version still has it, but in version 2.0.0-rc3 has.

Comment: @freakTheMighty I haven't tried it but I think you can.

re #6 I think you can define getters in the model definition which create proper virtual fields.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#defining-as-part-of-the-model-options